# Packages to use in python for the creation of a database table comparison tool

Tags: database, python-3.x, tuples, comparison

I was tasked with developing a tool that will accept a few parameters and then query 2 databases based on a list of tables.

There are 3 possible database options, a connection to Netezza, a connection to Oracle, or a connection to a DB2 Mainframe. In theory they will pass me the type of connection, hostname, port, database name,  username, and password.

The query will take a table from the list, query both databases and compare the data in the table across the 2 DBs.

For the connection to Netezza i am using pyodbc, for the connection to Oracle i am using cx_oracle, and for the connection to DB2 i am using ibm_db.

At the moment i was able to make a connection to each and i was able to return the column metadata of the table in each db as well as a result set from each.

There are a few things i am trying to accomplish.

If the column is of a certain data type (i.e. decimal, integer) i want to sum all the values for that column in the table, if it is of any other datatype (i.e. string, date) i want to count do a count().

I would like to do this for the table in both DBs and then do a comparison of the column counts/totals and display the comparison in excel.

Finally i would like to do a column by column comparison of every row in the table in both DBs. If there are any differences in the field values for each row then the entire row will be displayed in an excel spreadsheet.

What i am wondering is if there are any packages in python that i can use to perform these table like operations.

Please see the code below for what i have so far.

```
import pyodbc
import ibm_db
import cx_Oracle
import collections

class DatabaseConnection(object):

    def __init__(self, connection_type, hostname_or_ip, port, database_or_sid, username, password):
        self.port = port
        self.connection_type = connection_type
        self.hostname_or_ip = hostname_or_ip
        self.database_or_sid = database_or_sid
        self.username = username
        self.password = password
        self.dsn = "GEMPROD"
        self.connection_string = ""
        self.conn = ""

    def __enter__(self):
        if self.connection_type == "Netezza":
            self.connection_string = "DRIVER={NetezzaSQL};SERVER=" + self.hostname_or_ip + ";PORT="+ self.port + \
                                    ";DATABASE=" + self.database_or_sid + ";UID=" + self.username + ";PWD=" + self.password
            self.conn = pyodbc.connect(self.connection_string)
            return self.conn
        elif self.connection_type == "Oracle":
            dsn_tns = cx_Oracle.makedsn(self.hostname_or_ip, self.port, self.database_or_sid)
            self.conn = cx_Oracle.connect(user=self.username, password=self.password, dsn=dsn_tns)
            return self.conn
        elif self.connection_type == "DB2":
            self.connection_string = "Database=" + self.database_or_sid + ";HOSTNAME=" + self.hostname_or_ip + \
                                     ";PORT=" + self.port + ";PROTOCOL=TCPIP;UID=" + self.username + ";PWD=" + \
                                     self.password + ";"
            #self.conn = ibm_db.connect(self.connection_string, "", "")
            self.conn = ibm_db.connect('DSN=' + self.dsn, self.username, self.password)
            return self.conn
        pass

    def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
        if self.connection_type == "Netezza":
            self.conn.close()
        elif self.connection_type == "DB2":
            ibm_db.close(self.conn)
        elif self.connection_type == "Oracle":
            self.conn.close
        pass

    def __repr__(self):
            return '%s%s' % (self.__class__.__name__, self.dsn)

    def query(self, query, params):
        pass


#database_column_metadata = collections.namedtuple('DatabaseColumnMetadata','index column_name data_type')
#database_field = collections.namedtuple('', '')

table_list = ['BNR_CIF_25DAY_RPT', table2]
sort_column = None
with DatabaseConnection('Netezza', ip, port, database, username, pwd) as connection_one:
    print('Netezza Query:')
    for table in table_list:
        cursor = connection_one.cursor()
        netezza_rows = cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM BNR_CIF_25DAY_RPT LIMIT 1")
        column_list = netezza_rows.description
        sort_column = str(column_list[0][0])
        netezza_query = "SELECT * FROM BNR_CIF_25DAY_RPT ORDER BY " + sort_column + " ASC LIMIT 10"
        netezza_rows = cursor.execute(netezza_query)
        print(column_list)
        netezza_column_list = []
        for idx, column in enumerate(column_list):
            column_name, data_type, *rest = column
            netezza_column_list.append((idx, column_name, data_type))
        for row in netezza_rows:
            print(row, end='\n')
        for tup in netezza_column_list:
            print(tup, end='\n')
        print('Netezza row count:', str(netezza_rows.rowcount) + '\n')
        cursor.close()

with DatabaseConnection('Oracle', hostname, port, SID, username, pwd) as connection_two:
    print('Oracle Query:')
    for table in table_list:
        try:
            cursor = connection_two.cursor()
            oracle_rows = cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM BNR_CIF_25DAY_RPT WHERE ROWNUM <= 1")
            column_list = oracle_rows.description
            sort_column = column_list[0][0]
            oracle_query = "SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM BNR_CIF_25DAY_RPT ORDER BY " + sort_column + " ASC) WHERE ROWNUM <=10"
            oracle_rows = cursor.execute(oracle_query)
            print(column_list)
            oracle_column_list = []
            for idx, column in enumerate(column_list):
                column_name, data_type, *rest = column
                oracle_column_list.append((idx, column_name, data_type))
            for row in oracle_rows:
                print(row, end='\n')
            for tup in oracle_column_list:
                print(tup, end='\n')
            print('Oracle row count:', str(oracle_rows.rowcount) + '\n')
        except cx_Oracle.DatabaseError as e:
            print(str(e))
        finally:
            cursor.close()
```

Apologize for anything that didnt make sense and the poor code as i am new to Python and program is still in it's infancy.

Comment: I believe that what i am looking for is something like pandas. Not sure if this is the best option.

Answer (score 0):

This is not exactly python based solution but we used to do it in our shop to compare netezza and Oracle using fluid query . [Fluid query](https://www-01.ibm.com/common/ssi/cgi-bin/ssialias?htmlfid=WAS12388USEN)

Comment: Appreciate the response. Seems like Fluid Query would be useful. Not sure if it would work from a automated monitoring perspective.